# Fetching data before opening modal in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Thanks for checking this post.
I'm new to React and I have a question about fetching data before opening a modal.

I have a card list and when I click on a card, a modal pops up with the data of clicked item (handleModal function takes id of clicked item). And I want the data inside already without delay every time the modal pops up.

```
const [eachUser, setEachUser] = useState({});
const [isModalOn, setIsModalOn] = useState(false);

const loadDetailInfo = async id => {
  if (isModalOn) {
      return;
   }
  await axios
    .get(`${API}/api/users/${id}`)
    .then(res => setEachUser(res.data.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};


const handleModal = id => {
   if (!isModalOn) {
     setEachUser('');
   }
   loadDetailInfo(id);
   setIsModalOn(!isModalOn);
};

return (
<>
  <CardList data={filteredUser} handleModal={handleModal} />
  {isModalOn && <Modal data={eachUser} handleModal={handleModal}/>}
</>
 );
```

But with this code, since it takes time to fetch data from the API, modal shows blank view at first and I don't know how to fix this.

I've tried useEffect and putting the loadDetailInfo function inside with the id state in a dependency array but I couldn't fix it for some reason..

It would be really appreciate if you give me some advice.Thank you for your time and advice in advance.

Comment: This is more of a UX problem. If your Modal depends on async data, show a loading state or a spinner to the user, and when the data is fetched, show the Modal.

Comment: +1 for @PsyGik. 

Another way could to preload the data when loading the card list it self. 
Then rather then loading data from server, you can fetch it from store which is much faster.

You should be careful however if the combined data size is too much.

Comment: @PsyGik Thank you for your comment! Maybe I have to consider more about UX before coding. I decided to show a loading spinner and show modal after data is fetched. Thanks again!

Comment: @DivineCoder Thank you for your comment too !! I wonder if you meant by using state  management library like Redux ?

Comment: Yes, exactly @ElenaPark